# What does “jaw-breaking” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

"India’s prime minister has promised a "jaw-breaking response" to the killing of 40 Indian paramilitary police." What does “jaw-breaking response” mean?

Comment: What response did the PM ultimately propose?  And were the news stories about the PM delivering on his promise or his falling short?

Answer (score 1):

"Jaw-breaking response" means to give such an answer that the person will be unable to argue further. मुह तोड़ जवाब

Comment: Who will be unable to argue further? The speaker or the listeners?

Comment: PM will give a jaw-breaking response to the people who have killed Indian paramilitary police

Answer (score 0):

The response will be more than words. The term jaw-breaking refers to violence, as in a punch to the jaw. The prime minister is assuring the victims and their families that the response will be much more than mere words and likely a physical if not violent pursuit and prosecution of the offenders.

Comment: Either that or the PM will feed his opponents hard candies.  "Jaw-breaker", in the US, is a hard candy that is apt to break your teeth if you try to chew it.